# Muscle layers of pharynx and gi tract

Tags: human-anatomy, digestive-system

Why does pharynx have an internal longitudinal muscle layer and external circular muscle layer, while oesophagus and the rest of gastrointestinal tract have inner circular and outer longitudinal muscle layer?